# Backup 2003 AD and restore onto 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

Currently I have a 2003 box running AD as the root OS on the system. I'd like to do this:

1. Backup the AD and DNS configuration on the 2003 box.
2. Wipe the drive(s) and install Hyper-V 2008 R2 as the root OS.
3. Create a new VM with 2008 R2.
4. Restore backup from step 1 onto new VM.

I can't find instructions for doing the back/restore portion. I'm hoping someone can offer some guidance.

Comment: this is probably the worst idea I have heard in a long time...why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: @August, can you elaborate? This is a home configuration, not corporate.

Comment: @Josh M. - I suspect August is saying "You can't restore a backup from an older version of AD onto a newer version of AD" in a roundabout way. It won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do with Active Directory in that manner. What you *can* do (in very broad terms) is:

- Setup your new Windows Server 2008 R2 VM on another machine, configuring it to use your existing Windows Server 2003 instance as its DNS server
- Join the Windows Server 2008 R2 instance to your existing Active Directory domain and promote it to being a Domain Controller
- Transfer the FSMO roles from the existing W2K3 DC to the new W2K8R2 DC
- Demote the W2K3 DC from being a DC to a member server and disjoin it from the domain
- Wipe the physical computer that was running W2K3, install W2K8R2 Hyper-V
- Migrate the W2K8R2 DC VM over to the W2K8R2 Hyper-V computer

There's no other way to do what you're looking for in a "supported" manner (or, for that matter, in any manner I can think of that would preserve the existing AD environment).

Comment: This is a good solution. I will install Hyper-V on another box and get the VM setup, AD, promote, etc. Then move it over to the server after demoting/disjoining the 2003 AD and installing Hyper-V in its place. Then just move the VM over. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 3):

No. Don't do it. Setup a second DC. Replicate to that. Demote the first one. Wipe the machine. Install WS 2008 on it. You should have a second DC around anyways so this would be your best solution. A DC for a small organization doesn't need much in terms of resources. Just throw it on an old PC.